# Efficient data structure to map integer-to-integer with find & insert, no allocations and fixed upper bound

Tags: c++, optimization, dictionary, data-structures, hashtable

I am looking for input on an associative data structure that might take advantage of the specific criteria of my use case.

Currently I am using a red/black tree to implement a dictionary that maps keys to values (in my case integers to addresses).

In my use case, the maximum number of elements is known up front (1024), and I will only ever be inserting and searching. Searching happens twenty times more often than inserting. At the end of the process I clear the structure and repeat again. There can be no allocations during use - only the initial up front one. Unfortunately, the STL and recent versions of C++ are not available.

Any insight?

Comment: Implement a hash-table instead. Since you know the maximum number of elements up front this is smooth sailing (i.e., you won't need a sophisticated hash function).

Comment: @40two Given that the key is randomly distributed can you recommend an efficient hash function? And what kind of hash-table - linear probing, buckets?

Comment: Use a 1024 sized buffer. Key will be used for indexing the buffer.

Comment: @40two - I don't understand. The key is a random value that exceeds the size of the table, so I can't simply index into the buffer using the key. Each key is unique, but it doesn't follow a pattern that can be turned into a linear key.

Comment: For N=1024 a linear search may be faster than any fancier data structure here.

Comment: @Billy ONeal Interesting - I had not thought about that. Would you just throw the elements into the array and leave them unsorted? I'll give it a try!

Comment: @Steven its at least worth benchmarking given how easy it is to benchmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing a simple linear-probe HashTable from an example [here](http://preshing.com/20130107/this-hash-table-is-faster-than-a-judy-array/). I used the [MurmurHash3](https://code.google.com/p/smhasher/wiki/MurmurHash3) hash function since my data is randomized.

I modified the hash table in the following ways:

1. The size is a template parameter. Internally, the size is doubled. The implementation requires power of 2 sizes, and traditionally resizes at 75% occupation. Since I know I am going to be filling up the hash table, I pre-emptively **double it's capacity** to keep it sparse enough. This might be less efficient when adding small number of objects, but it is more efficient once the capacity starts to fill up. Since I cannot resize it I chose to start it doubled in size.
2. I do not allow keys with a value of zero to be stored. This is okay for my application and it keeps the code simple.
3. All resizing and deleting is removed, replaced by a single clear operation which performs a memset.
4. I chose to inline the insert and lookup functions since they are quite small.

It is faster than my red/black tree implementation before. The only change I might make is to revisit the hashing scheme to see if there is something in the source keys that would help make a cheaper hash.

Billy ONeal suggested, given a small number of elements (1024) that a simple linear search in a fixed array would be faster. I followed his advice and implemented one for side by side comparison. On my target hardware (roughly first generation iPhone) the hash table outperformed a linear search by a factor of two to one. At smaller sizes (256 elements) the hash table was still superior. Of course these values are hardware dependant. Cache line sizes and memory access speed are terrible in my environment. However, others looking for a solution to this problem would be smart to follow his advice and try and profile it first.

Comment: Doubling the table size likely is a pessimization. Have you measured?

Comment: @ Billy ONeal No I did not measure it - I went by the observation that most expanding hash tables double in size at 60-80% occupation. With a perfect hash I wouldn't need any, but that's not the case here. I am seeing some collisions. You are right that I need to profile it and see how much impact a highly populated hash table is at 1024 elements.